# How to generate key in AndroidKeyStore encrypted by another key?

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, android-keystore

I am using fingerprint authentication in my application. It works well, but when setUserAuthenticationRequired is enabled, we can call doFinal() method only one time. But I need to call it multiple times to decrypt several strings.

I want to use fingerprint key to encrypt another key and this second use to encrypt my data. So I could call doFinal() multiple times. Also it preferable to store both keys in AndroidKeyStore if it possible. So when I need to decrypt my data I want to retrieve first key by fingerprint authentication, then retrieve second key using first key and finally decrypt all my data using second key.

But how to create second key encrypted by first (fingerprint) key? Is it possible to store second key in AndroidKeyStore?

This code I am using to create key for fingerprint authentication:

```
val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
    val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MyKeyAlias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    keyGenerator.init(builder.build())
    keyGenerator.generateKey()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by saying you can only call doFinal() one time ..

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen this is a normal behaviour when you are using setUserAuthenticationRequired. In this case you can use retrieved key only one time. After that the key became invalidated and you have to request the key again. Sure you can try to use setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds() but it doesn't works as desired with BiometricPrompt.